# NodeJS fetch returns ECONNREFUSED error when executed in fs.writeFile callback

Tags: node.js, fs, fetch-api

I have some code where I have generated some json data, then I would like to

1. write it to a file, then
2. hit an api endpoint (a get request)

The issue I am running into is:
when I execute `fetch` after using `fs.writeFile` I get an `ECONNREFUSED` error.  If I do not write the file, my get request to the endpoint is successful.
I am putting my fetch in the callback to the writeFile function - I have also tried `fs.writeFileSync(url)` which gives me the same results.  My full code requires writeFile to come first.

I noticed if I wrap `fetch` in a `setTimeout` with 10000ms, then fetch will work.  It *seems* as if `writeFile` isn't waiting long enough to execute the callback function.

Am I doing something incorrectly?  or How do I correctly write a file and then subsequently fetch API data?

I boiled down my code to the most minimal example to reproduce this behavior - as well as allowing node to correctly return the error messages. (using a fake URL for this example as the real url isn't publicly accessible)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');                                                                                                                                                     
const fs    = require('fs');                                                                                                                                                             

try {                                                                                                                                                                                    
    fs.writeFile('./example.json', JSON.stringify(['test', 'one', 'two']), () => {                                                                               
        fetch('http://www.example.com/api_endpoint?q=test')                                                                                 
            .then(console.info)                                                                                                                                                          
            .catch(console.error);                                                                                                                                                       
    });                                                                                                                                                                                  
} catch (e) {                                                                                                                                                                            
    console.info(e);                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

I'm running this in nodejs v10.15.1 on Linux Debian 8.11 (jessie)

Comment: What operating system and version of Node are you running? I was able to run your code fine on Windows 10, Node v12.15.0. It is indeed very weird that the state of a file handle interferes with your network request. (Possibly you have an extreme misconfiguration that limits your operating system or Node to one file handle at a time or something?)

Comment: I'm using node v10.15.1 on Linux (debian) - I just updated my question with that info too.

Comment: Could you test on a different machine or more recent Node? This seems like nothing short of an absolute bug, either in Node or in OS configuration. Your code is fine.

Comment: @apsillers I found the issue...  I wrote what I did wrong in an answer.  Thanks for confirming that I wasn't crazy :)  It got me to take another look which led me to catch the issue.

Comment: Hah! I would not have guessed "my file write in the client temporarily takes down the server, because they're the same machine"! `:)` Good detective work.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem, it's real silly...

My script is in the same repo as my API server.  When running the server in dev mode (`adonis serve --dev`), `fs.writeFile` triggers the file watcher to reload (of course), which temporarily disconnects the server.  It is very obvious *now* why it's not working.

The solution was to have the file watcher ignore the folder I am writing the json file to.

In my case (working with adonisjs) that is `adonis server --dev -i scripts`

Oddly enough, this is a project that worked a month ago and I didn't have this issue then.  I guess something changed in how I'm running it between then and now.